# Sistema de Mensagens

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou querendo implementar alguns elementos de comunicação entre os usuários da minha aplicação. Pensei em criar algo que permitisse o envio de mensagens, algo parecido com o Facebook, mas não precisa ser necessariamente em tempo real. Tenho até as tabelas prontas, porém, não sei por onde começar. Alguém sabe como fazer? Algum framework, tutorial, qualquer coisa pra eu pelo menos começar.

Comment: Explique-nos mais um pouco sobre teu projeto. Se é um sistema back-end, front-end, se estas mensagens serão vistas no refresh da página, como irão ficar dispostas, se serão várias mensagens por página...?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Então, basicamente meu projeto é um site onde as pessoas podem escrever livros e publica-los no próprio site. Para deixar mais interativo, eu pensei nessa ideia das mensagens. Dentro do perfil do usuário, teria um parte reservada para envio/recebimento de mensagens, quase como um e-mail. E ao acessar essa parte, o usuario teria as opções de ver as mensagens que ele recebeu, excluir e enviar mensagens, para qualquer membro cadastrado no site.

Comment: Então @RyanSantos tem uma API chamada SignaIR. Ela pode te ajudar a pelo menos ter um norte nessa situação de mensagem. Não vou mandar em resposta pelo fato de ser muito grande o tutorial que [tem nesse link](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc) no site asp.net/mvc que é basicamente a construção de um chat. É em tempo real, mas pode ajudar a trilhar um caminho.

Comment: @ÉrikThiago É um começo, vou ver se acho exemplos mais avançados. Valeu.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nos outros tutos que tem no site que te mandei também. La tem vários !